# WSO2 Change Log File Location

Tags: logging, configuration, wso2

In WSO2 the log files are in the folder `WSO2_HOME/repository/logs`. But I need to put all logs in a separate directory outside of the WSO2_HOME.

Typically all log files like `wso2carbon.log`, `audit.log`, ...

**Where can the location of these WSO2 log files be changed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/  and you need to edit the log4j.properties file 
For wso2carbon log file you need to edit "CARBON_LOGFILE" and give the full URL for "log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.Fil" property

```
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2carbon${instance.log}.log
```

For audit log you need to edit AUDIT_LOGFILE appender and change "log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.File" property

```
log4j.appender.AUDIT_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/audit.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the `log4j.properties` under the path `WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/` where all log files can be configured. [Link to the documentation from WSO2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Setting+Up+Logging).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change location of all logs you need to:

1. edit log4j.properties file in CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/ directory
2. configure HTTP Access log file by changing
   CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
3. edit log4j.properties file in org.wso2.carbon.server-x.x.x.jar located in
   CARBON_HOME/lib/ directory

(Btw don't forget to change the permissions on your new log directory)

You can find more information in this blog. http://udarakr.blogspot.com/2015/01/change-location-of-wso2-carbon-server.html